# Change logo after scrolling - problem with mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wrote a code that changes the menu logo after scrolling.
After scrolling, the code also adds a class (different styles - top-nav-collapse has transparent background). For transparent background I want to logo-white.png, after scrolling logo.png (white background). Everything is ok, but i want to always logo.png for mobiles devices 768px (mobile menu always has white background). Mobile devices logo shouldn't chage.

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");   
        $('.nav-logo img').attr('src','https://example.com/images/logo.png');
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");   
        $('.nav-logo img').attr('src','https://example.com/images/logo-white.png');
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="nav-logo"><img src="images/logo-white.png"></a>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a check with something like `$(window).width() < 769`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `window.matchMedia` which you can use in javascript to get the target. An example could be

```
if(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)")) {
    //your javascript code targeting that media
}
```

This function supports complex media queries as you specify them in CSS. Just try to match your target media and apply `window.scroll` function